# Azure ARM template Logic App authorize OneDrive For Business account when Deploy

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-logic-apps, azure-rm-template

I am having problems when deploying a Logic App template in Azure. Everything goes Ok but connection with OneDrive For Business is not authenticated. Which parameter do I need in my template in order to make the connection automatically?

This is my connection resource code:

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
  "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
  "name": "[parameters('connections_onedriveforbusiness_name')]",
  "location": "westeurope",
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "[parameters('onedrive_email_account')]",
    "customParameterValues": {},
    "api": {
      "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westeurope/managedApis/', parameters('connections_onedriveforbusiness_name'))]"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OneDrive For Business Connections is an OAuth connection. So we don't have to add any content to the "parameterValues".

The resource code

```
{
  "type": "Microsoft.Web/connections",
  "apiVersion": "2016-06-01",
  "name": "[parameters('connections_onedriveforbusiness_name')]",
  "location": "westeurope",
  "properties": {
    "displayName": "[parameters('onedrive_email_account')]",
    "api": {
    "id": "[concat(subscription().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/westeurope/managedApis/',parameters('connections_onedriveforbusiness_name'))]",
     "parameterValues": { }
    }
  }
}
```

Once you finish the ARM template deployment, you need to open the OneDrive For Business Connection to authenticate.

[image]

If you don't like to open the portal. You can also use [LogicAppConnectionAuth](https://github.com/logicappsio/LogicAppConnectionAuth) PowerShell script. 
For more details, please refer to https://www.bruttin.com/2017/06/13/deploy-logic-app-with-arm.html

Comment: I wanted to know if there is any way to get the authentication automatically without any script. Like Service Bus connectionString, you get the key using:
          "connectionString": "[listkeys(variables('authRuleResourceId'), variables('sbVersion')).primaryConnectionString]"

Something like that I'm looking for.